# How open STDIN/STDOUT handles and work with utf8 encoding correctly?

Tags: perl, utf-8, file-io

I have utf8 characters in my code. So I do:

```
use utf8;

my $line =  'ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р';
print $line; # Wide character in print at ...
```

Then I thought that my STDOUT should be in `utf8`:

```
use utf8;
use open IO => ':utf8 :std';

my $line =  'ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р';
print $line; # Wide character in print at ...
```

Why when I say perl to use `utf8` while my source code has `utf8` characters I get the error?

In same time:

No error:

```
my $line =  'ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р';
print $line;
```

No error:

```
use open IO => ':utf8 :std';

my $line =  'ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р';
print $line;
```

How I should open my filehandles and work correctly with `utf8`?

**UPD**
Actually I have this code. It do not match:

```
use open IO => ':utf8 :std';

my $line =  'ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р';
my @match =  $line =~ m/(вiд|от|від)/i;
print "$line -> $1 \n";
```

Unfortunately regex is not matched. The output is:

```
ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р ->
```

Then I add `utf8` pragma:

```
use utf8;
use open IO => ':utf8 :std';

my $line =  'ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р';
my @match =  $line =~ m/(вiд|от|від)/i;
print "$line -> $1 \n";
```

Now regex is matched, but warning is issued

```
Wide character in print at t2.pl line 17.
ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р -> ВIД
```

Comment: in short: `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`

Comment: @zdim: then I get this: `ÐÐ. Ð ÐÐ¥. â
              382 ÐIÐ 03.02.2020Ð  -> `

Comment: `use open` won't affect the stdout because it's already opened. `binmode STDOUT, ":utf8"` works for me.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I don't get anything wrong, in a one-liner: `perl -wE'use open ":std", ":encoding(UTF-8)"; use utf8; $s = q(ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р); say $s'`.  You still need `use utf8;` -- that's for the source itself.

Comment: @EugenKonkov I mean, replace what you have with what I show (and keep `use utf8;`).  That `':utf8 :std'` as one string doesn't mean anything for `use open`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank @Grinnz in IRC

Next code works:

```
use utf8;
use open ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';

my $line =  'ЗГ. РАХ. №382 ВIД 03.02.2020Р';
my @match =  $line =~ m/(вiд|от|від)/i;
print "$line -> $1 \n";
```

Notices:
@Grinnz adviced to use https://metacpan.org/pod/open::layers
because `:std is not a layer, it must be its own argument in the list`

Also I should not use `:utf8` [because](https://perldoc.pl/5.31.10/PerlIO#:utf8)

> CAUTION: Do not use this layer to translate from UTF-8 bytes, as invalid UTF-8 or binary data will result in malformed Perl strings. It is unlikely to produce invalid UTF-8 when used for output, though it will instead produce UTF-EBCDIC on EBCDIC systems. The :encoding(UTF-8) layer (hyphen is significant) is preferred as it will ensure translation between valid UTF-8 bytes and valid Unicode characters.

Comment: @zdim: yes, you are correct. I just forget to copy/paste that. Code is fixed

Comment: FWIW, notice that `use open ':encoding(UTF-8)', ':std';` is not limited to changing the encoding of the standard in/out/err handles, but it will also affect whatever files you open from your script, including any binary files you may want to pass the data read from to `unpack`, etc.

Comment: You can avoid this by putting the `use open` in its own lexical scope, or instead doing `binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)'` yourself, or using open::layers.